# pass uint256[] from Python to Solidity

Tags: python, solidity

I have a struct in my Solidity:

```
struct NFTBatchVoucher {
    uint256[] ids;
    uint256[] amounts;
    uint256 minPrice;
    string uri;
    bytes signature;
  }
```

And I'm trying to pass this type from Python to Solidity, but I don't know how to pass ids and amounts from Python.

If I pass a list like this: [1,1,1,1,1] the compiler complains I'm passing a list. (1,1,1,1,1) does not work either.

Nor does:

```
tokenIds = [i * 1e18 for i in range(start,end)]
```

or:

```
tokenIds = [int(i) for i in range(start,end)]
```

So what's the trick? What does the solc compiler expect?

Comment: there's not quite enough here to understand how you're trying to pass the value, but you might be looking for [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#examples)

Comment: share the solidity function pls

Comment: this is the function header:

function redeemBatch(address redeemer, NFTBatchVoucher calldata voucher) public payable returns (uint256[] memory) {

Comment: How are you interacting with the Solidity using Python? e.g. which library?

Comment: web3.py and some custom classes

Comment: Please include the function that you are calling the Solidity function from

Comment: Maybe the problem got something to do with pytest, will have to investigate later.

Comment: Please edit your question to include relevant Python code and any errors you get.